# What name will DependencyAttribute instance have if default constructor is used?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, attributes, unity-container, default-constructor

I have a code:

```
[Dependency] public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

While `DependencyAttribute` class has property `Name`.

What value will it contain in this case?

Will it be `null` or `nameof(MyProperty)`?

Unfortunately I have not seen source code of the `DependencyAttribute` class yet. Maybe someone can provide the link.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value will be null.  In the absence of an explicit name, null is the default name used by Unity (e.g. in calls to`RegisterType()`).  In terms of [`DependencyAttribute`](http://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/blob/master/source/Unity/Src/Attributes/DependencyAttribute.cs) specifically:

```
    public DependencyAttribute()
        : this(null) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create an instance of <see cref="DependencyAttribute"/> with the given name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Name to use when resolving this dependency.</param>
    public DependencyAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
```